Animated tv show that was on pop on the ps4 but I don’t remember much
I remember it started with a teenage boy stealing his father’s necklace and went surfing. Then the waves turned into a portal to another world. Then I remember he brought a ship to life by putting the pendant in a slot on the wheel and the wheel came to life.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you see this?  Can you describe the animation style?

I think it was sometime around 2018-19 and don’t know what the animation style is called but I think it is similar to the animated tv show “DEEP”.

At the end the mc had his phone taken and when and he got a call from the father in the human realm and the villain (which name I think might of hade gold in it I’m not sure though) and the father recognised the voice immediately and I think that was the end of the series

Is this Zak Storm (2016-2018)...?

When teenager Zak Storm takes his father's necklace and goes surfing, he is suddenly sucked by a giant wave and ends up in the Bermuda Triangle where he is picked up by a sentient pirate ship called the Chaos with a talking sword named Calabrass. He discovers that the necklace contains a gem called the Eye of Beru, which gives him special powers, and that in order to return home, he needs to become the captain of the Chaos and unite the Seven Seas. He assembles a band of misfits: a ghost boy, an Atlantean princess, a Viking, and a space alien.





It is Zak storm and I knew it was something that had a skull face on it and thanks.
